# React: How to refresh the data in the table after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to setup a refresh button so that when end user creates a new ticket i should be able to see the newly created ticket when i press refresh button. I am making use of Apollo client to get data from graphql server. I wonder how should i refresh my table i tried `forceUpdate` and `this.setState()`, i verified that it works by putting `{Math.random()}` in render function, however, it does not refresh and give new data, also tried putting the refresh button in button.js still issue is persisting. `window.location.reload()` works but that is not what i want, Is there something react can do like any lifecycle hook, i tried:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.ticket !== nextProps.ticket) {
     console.log(this.props.ticket)
  }
}
```

in table.js but it didn't do the trick or i have to make use of some Apollo client API. Please suggest, thanks in advance.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleRefresh =  this.handleRefresh.bind(this);

  }

  handleRefresh()  {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    const { data: {loading, getTickets}} = this.props;
    if(loading) {
      return <h4>Loading..</h4>
    }

    const Data = getTickets.map((ticket, id) => {
       return <Table ticket={ticket} key={id} />
    })


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Header />
          <Button className="lookup" bsStyle="info" bsSize="xsmall" 
onClick={this.handleRefresh}><h5>lookup 1</h5></Button><br/><br/>
              <div className="container" style={{overflowX:"auto"}}>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                  <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>TicketID</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Comment</th>
                              <th>EmpID</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              {Data}
                          </tbody>
                    </table>
               </div>
               <h4>Random number : {Math.random()}</h4>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
        );
    }
    }

    export default compose(
     graphql(GetTickets)
    )(App);
```

table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
          <tr>
                <td>{this.props.ticket.ticketID}</td>
                <td>{this.props.ticket.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.ticket.comment}</td>
                <td>{this.props.ticket.EmpID}</td>
          </tr>

        )
    }
}


Table.propTypes = {
    ticketID: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    EmpID: PropTypes.number,
    comment: PropTypes.string
}


export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graphql provides a `refetch` prop precisely for re-querying the database at any point.  just pass as a prop to your child component and call the function when you click the refresh button.  See the docs:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching

Comment: Yes it worked ! thanks, do you know how this.forceUpdate work, why it doesn't render the entire component ?

Comment: `forceUpdate` is specifically for re-rendering the entire component.  If you pass your data is props, react is smart enough to re-render based on new props so you shouldn't need to call `forceUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the graphQL datas as states for your component.